# Remove spaces and special characters from string

Tags: java, android, regex, string, replace

How can I format a string phone number to remove special characters and spaces?

The number is formatted like this (123) 123 1111

I am trying to make it look like this: 1231231111

So far I have this:

```
phone = phone.replaceAll("\\s","");
phone = phone.replaceAll("(","");
```

The first line will remove the spaces. Then I am having trouble removing the parentheses. Android studio underlines the `"("` and throws the error `unclosed group`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can remove everything but the digits:

```
phone = phone.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
```

Comment: Amazing, the number of other verbose answers many of which did not work at all, your succinct answer did it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

To remove all non-digit characters you can use

```
replaceAll("\\D+",""); \\ \D is negation of \d (where \d represents digit)
```

If you want to remove only spaces, `(` and `)` you can define your own [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) like

```
replaceAll("[\\s()]+","");
```

Anyway your problem was caused by fact that some of characters in regex are [special](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special). Among them there is `(` which can represent for instance start of the [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Similarly `)` can represent end of the group.

To make such special characters literals you need to escape them. You can do it many ways

- `"\\("` - standard escaping in regex
- `"[(]"` - escaping using character class
- `"\\Q(\\E"` - `\Q` and `\E` create quote - which means that regex metacharacters in this area should be treated as simple literals
- `Pattern.quote("("))` - this method uses `Pattern.LITERAL` flag inside regex compiler to point that metacharacters used in regex are simple literals without any special meaning

Comment: But It will remove + as well, e.g. If i take phone number with country code is +1(223) 223 12112
it will show me 122322312112 that will be an invalid!

Comment: @Faakhir This answer is based on OP requirement which states that `The number is formatted like this (123) 123 1111` so it excludes `+XX` part representing country code. But answer also contains version which describes how to remove *only* whitespaces and parenthesis, so it should leave other characters like `+` : `replaceAll("[\\s()]+","")`. Pick version which matches your needs.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `(` as it denotes a metacharacter (start of a group) in regular expressions. Same for `)`.

```
phone = phone.replaceAll("\\(","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // TODO code application logic here
  String str = "(test)";
  String replaced= str.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "");
  System.out.println(replaced);


}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? Code only answers are not acceptable on StackOverflow.